# Position of a modelmesh in XNA

Tags: model, matrix, xna, position

How do you find the vector 3 position of a mesh inside of a model in XNA(in global coordinates)?

I've made a model of a **simple lamp post** in blender. Where the light should be, I've put a **single vertice** as its own object and named it "Light", in the **position a typical light** would be in a lamp post.

In my XNA program, I want to put a floating point light at the position from the model. I can find the mesh by name. But need the **Vector3 position** of the "Light" mesh to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how the model is set up in terms of mesh/bone hierarchy. Ultimately, you multiply the light (bulb) matrix by its parent, who was first multiplied by its parent, and so on all the way to the root, then take the translation property of the result. There is a built in method to do this called Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(Matrix[])

```
Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[SimpleLampPostModel.Bones.Count];
SimpleLampPostModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

Vector3 lightPosition = transforms[SimpleLampPostModel.Meshes["light"].parentBone.Index].Translation;
lightPosition += modelWorld.Translation;// if the model is located in some arbitrary location in your 3d
                                        // world as represented by a world matrix (modelWorld)
```

Comment: Alright, that makes sence, and I just gave it a try where it certainly got close, [PICTURE LINK](http://s12.postimage.org/wm3fqi1i5/close.png).
I've checked the positions of the meshes and they're in the correct location.
Would there be any particular reason for the difference?/Is there some way for me to post/inbox you my code?

Comment: you can paste it to a pastebin and I can look at it from there. If you can, also export the fbx in ascii format and paste that too. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Alright, model is 7mb, so it didn't fit into pastebit(cap at 500kb). so I'll throw in the first section of it [Pastebin Model](http://pastebin.com/tMjNdLFA)

Here are the two classes I'm using that are particularly releveant.
[CModel](http://pastebin.com/YXWeCCCL) and the normal [Game1](http://pastebin.com/nDRqQLi6). As you'll find, my light is called "Light_down_255_255_255", this is because I was going to parse it in the program to make the light(face down, be white)
Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: my email address is in my account bio. I think I would need the whole 7mb to help